# Viewing Error Logs for Cloudflare Workers (Error 1101)

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm developing a script to run on Cloudflare Workers and it's throwing an error:

[image: Cloudflare error 1101]

> **If you are the owner of this website:** you should login to Cloudflare and check the error logs for app.something.workers.dev.

I can't however figure out where to find the logs once I logged into Cloudflare. Any idea?

I know I could use `try/catch` and return the error or post it elsewhere but I'm wondering how to get it with Cloudflare.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to post the exception to an error logging service, you can use Wrangler `tail` https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/debugging-workers

Comment: I'm aware of `wrangler tail` but I wasn't able to get it to work (connects but logs aren't shown). I'm not sure why. Maybe because it uses Argo Tunnel but it seems like that's [a paid service](https://developers.cloudflare.com/argo-tunnel/quickstart#how-much-does-argo-tunnel-cost) (Argo Smart Routing). The error page says "you should _login to Cloudflare_ and check the error logs for..." which seems like there might be a way to also see them via the web console.